# Comprobar valor String en SQL

Tags: mysql, string, trigger

estoy creando un trigger en SQL, en el cual uso las UDF para invocar a un código JAVA. dicho código java devuelve un string, del cual tengo que comprobar el valor para permitir una acción o no. ¿que función de SQL puedo utilizar para comprobar el contenido de ese String en una condición IF?

**CODIGO TRIGGER:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER ContentInsert

BEFORE INSERT ON joomladb.joomla_content
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
#DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE status CHAR(10);


SET status = sys_exec('java /rutadelarchivo/check_status.jar');

IF status NOT IN ("off") THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' -- "unhandled user-defined exception"
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ' Cerrado';
END IF;
END
```

**CODIGO JAVA:**

```
public class check_status {
final static String APP_ID ="CADENADEEJEMPLO";

public static String principal_status(String accountId){
    LatchApp latch= new LatchApp(APP_ID,LATCH_SECRET);
    LatchResponse response=latch.status(accountId);
    String status=response.getData().get("operations").getAsJsonObject().get(APP_ID).getAsJsonObject().get("status").getAsString();
    return status;

}


}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir las partes relevantes de tu código? Lee [ask] para tener más detalles sobre cómo hacer preguntas bien recibidas :)

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ya he añadido el código, a ver si me podéis echar una mano

Answer (score 0):

En estándar SQL se usa el = si sabes que la cadena va a coincidir y no es una sub-cadena dentro de la misma, de lo contrario tendrás que usar LIKE.

```
if status = "off" then
```

con LIKE

```
if status like '%off%' then
```

Te dejo un manual de MySql, ten en cuenta que puede variar un poco según el motor de base de datos que uses.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html